# How I Use spring-data-jpa mongoRepository to query and update?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Here is my Entity

```
@Document(collection = "deviceConfig")
@Data
@Builder
public class DbDeviceConfig {
    private ObjectId _id;

//    @Field("id")
//    @Id
//    private String id;

    private String deviceId;

    private String enterpriseId;


    private Integer state;


    private String cfgKey;


    @JsonSerialize
    private String cfgValue;


    private Long cfgDate;


    private Long reportDate;


    private Integer reportCode;


    private String reportMsg;
}
```

As you can see I Notes the @Id
since in my situation，each device will have only one cfgValue of specific cfgKey
so the enterpriseId and deviceId and cfgKey will keep it unique
i wrote the mongotemplate update sql

```
Query updateQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("enterpriseId").is(enterpriseId)
                    .and("cfgKey").is(batchAddDeviceConfig.getCfgKey())
                    .and("deviceId").is(deviceId));
            Update update = new Update();
            update.set("cfgDate", System.currentTimeMillis());
            update.set("cfgValue", batchAddDeviceConfig.getCfgValue());
            update.set("state", batchAddDeviceConfig.getState());
            dataMongoTemplate.upsert(updateQuery, update, DbDeviceConfig.class, "deviceConfig");
```

but I dont know how to write the Corresponding spring jpa code
or maybe i should add a Business Id?
I am really confused,since mongodb already create a ObjectId

I also search for other people's solution
it seems i can use this way

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Space c SET c.owner = :name WHERE c.id = :id")
Integer setNameForId(@Param("name") String name, @Param("id")
```

but that would be like lots of Parameter
please help me QAQ

Comment: Here is some reference information about using MongoDB and Spring Data APIs: [Spring Data MongoDB - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/). There are couple of ways you can do CRUD operations - using `MongoRepository` and the `MongoTemplate` APIs.

Comment: @prasad_ thank you,I will pay more attention to this document :)

Comment: Are you using Spring Data JPA or Spring Data MongoDb. These are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Data JPA, then you can fetch the entity from database using
`repository.findBy....()` methods, set the updated values in fetched entity and then call `repository.save(entity)` on it. Hibernate will take care of this and it will update your entity. However it will generate update query for all fields. If you want to update only changed fields, then you can use `@DynamicUpdate` on your entity class.

Comment: thank you，i make it worked by your way.But if i save a lot of deviceConfigs，will it  be low efficiency because each one will need to be find and save?Have you met this kind of situation?But thank you again,this bring me to correct way to use Spring-JPA :)

Comment: If you want some more efficiency then you can skip find calls and update directly the way you used in question i.e. using UPDATE in @Query. You can also find multiple records in single query to gain performance and then update them. If you want to make fast your query execution then you also can create index for the fields you are querying.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers in this thread are problematic... if you findBy and then save you are in fact doing something that is NOT atomic. If you are looking for an atomic way to do this, then you should keep in mind that the simplest way (I think the only way), is to use the mongo template with the update function...

The spring data repository option, as I see it, is more of a convenience option.

**(Edited here as an answer to one of the comments)**

Let's say that you want to do an $inc operation. This operation reads a field increments it and writes it back to the DB in an atomic way. Doing so with MongoTemplate in spring is very easy:

```
    Update update = new Update();
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(id));
    update.inc("upvoteCount");
    template.updateFirst(query, update, "post");
```

The query finds the document you need and then the update updates it.

I searched for quite a long while and I couldn't find a way to do this using spring data repository...

I might be wrong... but I don't think such a way even exists... if it does, I would love for someone to point it out to me

Comment: Can you explain with some samples for better understanding.

Comment: I answered your comment by editing my answer, because it was too long for a comment....